# Why use two activities and two fragments when one activity suffices

Tags: android, android-fragments

[image: Fragment usage]

This is the image explaining the usage of fragments. The first image shows `two fragments` and `two activities`.

Lame doubt. Why use two activities when the sole concept of using fragments is err.. using fragments instead of switching activities.

Comment: No reason .. who said you should?

Comment: Exactly!!! Am I free to use one activity and two fragments? Or is there any design philosophy suggesting otherwise?

Comment: I think it is perfectly acceptable with a Single Activity design these days. Although I personally think that Login screens and the like makes sense to maintain in its own Activity for instance. Maybe it is easier to maintain backwards compatibility with really old devices using the suggested design in the image.

Comment: Actually I have used a single Activity for almost the exact situation sketched in the image.

Comment: I'm so glad to hear that!! This single image was pestering my mind for a very long time. Thank you @cYrixmorten

Comment: I guess both ways are fine. I would go with the official way where you do actually create a new activity on smaller screens. I dont get this either LOL.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on your goals you can do it either way.

The method shown in the guide can be implemented entirely in XML layout files so it is a better method to teach to a new user of fragments.

The method you suggest requires the developer to manage fragment transactions in code, which is not too difficult, but why do it if your app does not have any special behavior that requires the extra work.

Also, since the animated transitions between fragments look different than activity transitions, your method will reveal the use of fragments at the user level. The method in the guide uses fragments as a modular programming technique that is transparent to the user.

You end up with an app that uses available space on all device types, but on a small device it acts just like a classic app that users already understand.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is that when you have extra room (such as on a tablet), you can display the content from what would have been two activities side-by-side rather than as two separate activities.

Think about a mail application. On a phone, you fn really only fit the list of mail on a screen, and you click on one to open the content of that mail on another screen.

If you did that on a tablet, there's a huge amount of wasted space; you can display the list of mail on the left side of the screen, and the selected mail's contents on the right side.

Because the list UI is the same in both examples, and the mail-display UI is the same in both as well, you can reuse that UI by including them as fragments. The logic for those UIs is also self-contained in the corresponding Fragment classes.

This allows the user to see more content with fewer activity switches.

Comment: That's a perfect explanation but my actual question was, if you are to develop an app, say the mail app, for a mobile phone, when switching between the list of mail screen and the content of mail, would you use two activities and two fragments (as the training guide image suggests) or one activity and two fragments.

Comment: I see - you could do it either way, swapping fragments in a single activity or switching activities. The nice thing about using separate activities, though, is that you can more easily have alternate layouts for how to arrange those fragments using the resource folders, vs having logic in your activity to try to determine how to position them.